# ngx-permission shows or hides a div but how to disable field or a div based on role permission in angular 8?

Tags: angular

```
   <div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="testing role based permission"></input></div>
   </div>
```

It shows or hides a div but doesn't disable it.

Comment: do you want to disable `input` inside the `div` ?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to disable a div, that div may contain n number of input fields or action buttons based on role. Manually I can set [disabled] but I am looking for better way like ngx-permission

Comment: You can try this [link](https://imdurgeshpal.medium.com/enable-disable-all-dom-elements-inside-div-in-angular-using-directive-56ca4602ab7b). However, it is not for `ngxPermissionsOnly`.

Comment: Thank you @SJNF, this is  a helpful link. It would be much better if there is any open library for role based disable directive.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late, but I am adding my answer in case anyone needs it later

simply **NgxPermissionsService** has function **hasPermission** that returns a boolean promise with whether the user has the given permission or not.

sample below

```
  async initForm() {
    const hasAccessToDisplayField: boolean = await this.ngxPermissionsService.hasPermission('permission_name');
    this.XForm = this.fb.group({
      certainField: [{ value: 'init value', disabled: !hasAccessToDisplayField }, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```